# Cayley's tree formula proof

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory, trees

I want to prove Cayley's tree formula that The number of distinct trees of order $n$ with a specified vertex set is $n^{n-2}$ using the fact that the number of trees on the set of $n$ vertices $\{1,2,...,n\}$ that the degree of ith vertex is $d_i$ is $\frac{(n-2)!}{(d_1-1)!...(d_n-1)!}$. But I don't know how to reach $n^{n-2}$ from this formula. Would you please help?

Comment: For a proof, see for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)#Counting_trees), section *Counting trees*. A further reference is Aigner & Ziegler (1998).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks but I don't want "a" proof. I want to prove this theorem by the formula I mentioned above.

Comment: And did you check that Aigner and Ziegler do not use this formula for a proof?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes. I think it's different

Comment: Some rewording would improve your Question.  Your problem statement is a "run-on sentence".  You might separate out the two propositions, one that you want to use and one that you want to prove.  If "order $n$" means $n$ vertices, then probably what you mean by "specified vertex set" is that the vertices are *labelled* (so that the counting you want to do treats the vertices as intrinsically distinguishable).

Answer (score 2):

In any $n$-vertex tree, we have $d_1 + \dots + d_n = 2(n-1)$ and therefore $(d_1 - 1) + \dots + (d_n - 1) = n-2$. Therefore $\frac{(n-2)!}{(d_1-1)! \cdots (d_n-1)!}$ is a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) that counts the number of $(n-2)$-tuples with $(d_1 - 1)$ $1$'s, $(d_2 - 1)$ $2$'s, and so on through $(d_n - 1)$ $n$'s.

If we sum over all choices of $(d_1, \dots, d_n)$ with $(d_1 - 1) + \dots + (d_n - 1) = n-2$, then we are just counting  the number of $(n-2)$-tuples made up of $1$'s, $2$'s, and so on through $n$'s. There are $n^{n-2}$ such tuples: each of $n-2$ positions can have one of $n$ values. Therefore there are $n^{n-2}$ labeled $n$-vertex trees in total.

If you are curious about whether these $(n-2)$-tuples have a further combinatorial meaning, look into [Prüfer codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence). These are also, incidentally, the easiest way to prove the $\frac{(n-2)!}{(d_1-1)! \cdots (d_n-1)!}$ formula.